# Update subscription when active messages in the subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using latest Azure service bus .Net core apis to manage subscription in a topic.
I was trying to Update a subscription using UpdateSubscriptionAsync() API to update the defaultMessageTimeToLive and lockDuration.
However when I update the subscription where a message is being processed, I got "SessionLockLostException: Session lock lost. Accept a new session is force detached"

Is that expected? 
I did not see any documentation warning against updating a subscription. Are we suppose to check that there are no messages in subscription before updating it?

Comment: I would suggest raising this with the broker team at https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues

Comment: Done. Thanks. https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/365